# safety git repo mirror

Tags: backup, git

I've read about `git clone --mirror <repo>` and `git remote update`. But it seems that would change local mirror no matter what happened in remote repo.

What I want is a mirror backup copy of the remote repo. But if remote repo branches are force-updated I want operation to fail. I also want to avoid existing branches being removed. When force-update is performed on remote repo manual intervention would be required - that I know how to do.

The purpose of such a mirror is to protect against incidental `force push` or deliberate repo hacking.

What I'm trying to ask is how to create and update a mirror git repo where the update would fail and keep existing content if origin repo branches are force-pushed or altered in some other way.

Comment: Remember that a git repo is _not_ a proper backup, even if it seems to have some of the properties of a backup.

Comment: A git repo is a proper backup of a another git repo because... well this is the content that needs to be backed-up. Of course reliability depends on configuration, underlying storage and number of copies. I'm simply asking how to perform the update of one backup copy. I think I'm going to use gerrit eventually. Which largely resolves my issue. But still I'm interested to know the answer of my original question.